# Group array structure with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

I need to rearrange from this array :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Qty
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 3
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Item No
        [1] => ABC345
        [2] => FGR8765
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Description
        [1] => Lores ipsum
        [2] => Dolores sit amet
        [3] => quasi architecto beatae:
        [4] => sed quia consequuntur
        [5] => consectetur, adipisci velit
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Price
        [1] => $10
        [2] => $20
    )
```

to become like this :

```
 Array
 (
   [0] => array(
     'Qty' => 1,
     'Item No' => 'ABC345',
     'Description' => 'Lores ipsum',
     'Price' => $10
   )
   [1] => array(
     'Qty' => 3,
     'Item No' => 'FGR8765',
     'Description' => 'Dolores sit amet quasi architecto beatae sed quia consequuntur consectetur, adipisci velit',
     'Price' => $20
   )
)
```

for the 0 index of each array is name of key : Qty, Item No, Description, Price.
and merge the value if index more than number of first array, as we can see on description key, the value array number 3,4,5 is merge to array number 2.

here is my attempt so far :

```
$itemList = array();
foreach($result as $i => $valueKey)
{
    if($i == 0) {
      $max = count($valueKey);
    }
    foreach($valueKey as $y => $item)
    {
        $itemList[] = array(
            $item[0] => $item
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: If two items will contain a first description, how the array will be changed ?

Comment: Have you got any control over the source of this array? It feels like it might be easier to fix the parsing step rather than trying to rebuild it from this structure.

Comment: This is a very unclear question. What happens if there is three items? How do you know where to split the description? All answers to this question in this state is just pure guesses and only a literal code to do what you want. None of them has a logic to handle three or more items. Or a first item with two description items.

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = array(/* input array */);
$output = array(/* output array */);

foreach ($input as $property)
{
    $propcount = count($property);
    for ($i = 1; $i < $propcount; $i++)
        $output[$i - 1][$property[0]] = $property[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```php
$input = [
    [ "Qty", 1, 3 ],
    [ "Item No", "ABC345", "FGR8765" ],
    [ "Description", "Lores ipsum", "Dolores sit amet", "quasi architecto beatae:", "sed quia consequuntur", "consectetur, adipisci velit" ],
    [ "Price", "$10", "$20" ]
];

$max = count($input[0]) - 1;
$output = array_reduce(
    $input,
    function (array $out, array $items) use ($max) {
        $header = array_shift($items);
        $redundant = array_splice($items, $max);

        foreach ($items as $idx => $value) {
            $out[$idx][$header] = $value;
        }

        foreach ($redundant as $value) {
            $out[$idx][$header] .= ' ' . $value;
        }

        return $out;
    },
    []
);

var_dump($output);
```

I would also recommend putting it in some function with a nice name.

Answer (score 0):

Hi II hove this will help you :)

```
$result = Array
(
    Array
    (
        "Qty", 1, 3
    ),
    Array
    (
        "Item No", "ABC345", "FGR8765"
    ),
    Array
    (
        "Description", "Lores ipsum", "Dolores sit amet", "quasi architecto beatae:", "sed quia consequuntur", "consectetur, adipisci velit"
    ),
    Array
    (
        "Price", "$10", "$20"
    )
);

$total_result = count($result);
$itemList = $final_result = array();
$i = 1;
foreach ($result as $res) {
    foreach ($result as $item) {
        if (isset($item[0])) {
            foreach ($item as $key => $val) {
                          $itemList[$item[0]] = ($item[$i]=="")?0:$item[$i];
            }
        }
    }
    $i++;
    $final_result[] = $itemList;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($final_result);
```